# How to get the count of rows from a dynamic html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an empty tbody that gets added to whenever a user completes the form. Eventually this table data will be stored in a database, but for now it is not. This is my table setup:

```
<div class="formContainer">
        <form id="form1">
          <b>Step Number: </b><input type="number" id = "theStep" name="step" required></br>
          <b>First Name: </b> <input type="text" name="firstName" required></br>
          <b>Last Name: </b><input type="text" name="lastName" required></br>
          <b>Alias: </b><input type="text" name="alias" required></br>
          <b>Today's Date: </b><input type="date" id="theDate" name="submitDate" required></br>
          <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">
        </form>
      </div>

      <h2>Step Approvals</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="stepTable" class="table table-striped table-sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Step</td>
              <td>First Name</td>
              <td>Last Name</td>
              <td>Alias</td>
              <td>Submission Date</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="displayArea"></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

I want to automatically fill the form with the entry number so I am trying to keep track of how many entries there are by counting the number of rows in the table. This is what I tried but it only gives me a 'null' value even after I add entries/rows to the table:

```
var setStep = $('#stepTable > tbody >tr').length;
  if (setStep = 'null') {
    $("#theStep").attr("value", 1)
  } else {
    $("#theStep").attr("value", setStep + 1)
    };
```

Every time I toggle the form, the 'step' field should be updated with the number of rows in the table + 1.

Comment: `.length` returns an integer, so `setStep` should never be equal to 'null', also `=` is for assignment, `==` or `===` are used for comparison. This is the problem `if (setStep = 'null')` you are assigning the value of 'null' to setStep, it needs to be compared with `==` or `===`

Comment: @JM2397 welcome to Stackoverflow. You should take the time to submit a question which hasn't got too many mistakes. Where should we start? the IDs you refer in JS code is nowhere in HTML so what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @caramba my fault, new to stack and new to coding in general. I included the form portion of the html which should include the IDs I refer to.

Comment: @JM2397 I gave you the answer in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row number of a table using `document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length`

```js
var rowCount = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length; // For rows
var colCount = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells.length; // For columns
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "ROW COUNT: " + rowCount;
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML += "<br/>COL COUNT: " + colCount;
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
    ROW 1
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    ROW 2
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    
<div id="count"></div>
```